# Implementing an image viewer using CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLr1oswr/)) implements an image viewer in CSS

[image: image viewer]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Trains, Planes, Automobiles, and Boats</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { background:#ddd; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
        #foo { position:absolute; left:5%; width:60%; top:5%; height:80%; background:#dcc; }
        #bar { position:absolute; left:70%; width:25%; top:5%; height:80%; background:#cbd; vertical-align: middle; }

        .fullwidth { width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; }

        .vcenter {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">
        <div class="vcenter"> 
            <img class="fullwidth" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/19623/philrich123-A380.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bar">
        <img class="fullwidth" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/4703/ryanlerch-Steam-Train-Engine.png" />
        <img class="fullwidth" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/19623/philrich123-A380.png" />
        <img class="fullwidth" src="http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/74557/rally-car.png" />
        <img class="fullwidth" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/196201/Model-T-Ford.png&disposition=attachment" />
        <img class="fullwidth" src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/24418/Jarno-Boat-1.png&disposition=attachment" />
    </div>
</body>
```

How do I fix the following two bugs?

1. The `bar` side does not scroll.
2. The image in the `foo` side is not centered. The intention is to make all the image visible in the left side while filling its container in one dimension (vertical/horizontal) and being scaled in the other (horizontal/vertical) to remain at 1:1 ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  not sure I understood your question, but if you only want to make your right div scrollable then add this to your css

```
#bar{
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8kmbexam/1/)

To answer your second question (vertically centering the left image), add these rules to your `vcenter` class

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/8kmbexam/3/)

Comment: The `overflow: scroll;` is exactly right, but the second part only works if the foo container has a width/height that is less than that of the image (the plane). If width/height of foo is larger, the image is clipped.

Comment: According to your code the left image has he class `fullwidth` which includes the rule `width:100%`. In that case the plane image will always take 100% of the left div width.